# How to enable MIME in nginx server. (Locally)

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx

**How to enable MIME in nginx server.(Locally)**

**Getting an error while uploading image file.**

> "Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you
>   enable the php_fileinfo extension?)"

**In my laravel 5.6, I am validating image request on UserController.php.**

```
$this->validate($request, [
                'profile_photo' => 'required',
                'profile_photo.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);
```

Comment: what does your nginix configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uncomment the following line in your php.ini?

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

After that don't forget to restart the server